# How can I require conditional workflows to pass without blocking pull requests from being merged?

Tags: github-actions

When setting up CI with GitHub Actions I want two things:

1. To require workflows (e.g. backend unit testing) to pass before allowing pull requests to be merged.
2. To conditionally run workflows (e.g. backend unit testing only when a pull request changes files in the backend directory of my project).

In isolation these requirements work well:

1. I use [branch protection settings](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) to require status checks to pass before pull requests can be merged.
2. I can use the [GitHub Actions workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) to specify [which paths should trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) a workflow.

Combined there is a problem: If a pull request doesn't touch the backend files, then that workflow never runs and the status check never passes.

I would like to be able to have the best of both worlds: allow merge when all workflows which run pass. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible workarounds to achieve the behaviour of only requiring triggered workflows to pass:

1. Skip jobs within a workflow by making them conditional instead of the whole workflow. This works because skipped jobs are considered a success.

   - Requires the use of third-party actions (e.g. [paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) for conditions on changed paths).
   - Upsides

     - Runner minutes are minimised because no extra runner is introduced. If you're working in a private repository this important for billing (see details of [GitHub Actions pricing](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions)).
   - Downsides

     - DX - you can't tell at a glance which workflows ran fully on a PR.
     - DX - you have to introduce and maintain conditional job logic into workflows.
     - Runners are spun up needlessly just to skip the run.
2. Introduce a workflow which checks the status of other workflows on a pull request and passes when they all do. Make this the only required status check under branch protection.

   - The third-party action [wait-for-status-checks](https://github.com/poseidon/wait-for-status-checks) does this nicely out of the box.
   - Upsides

     - DX - it's clear at a glance which workflows actually ran.
     - DX - Simple to configure the new workflow and doesn't require introducing extra logic into others.
     - Runners aren't spun up needlessly just to skip a run.
   - Downsides

     - Introduces an extra runner which will always run at least as long as the longest workflow on a PR. In effect this doubles the runner minutes of your longest workflow. If you're working in a private repository this important for billing (see details of [GitHub Actions pricing](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions)).
3. Create a dummy workflow job of the same name which runs when the required workflow doesn't. This used to be recommended in [GitHub's documentation on handling skipped required checks](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks), but was removed because it creates a lot of maintenance burden and introduces odd cases where both checks can run on a pull request.

References:

- The long-standing community discussion on this scenario: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13690

Answer (score 0):

The [issue 13690](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13690#discussioncomment-8217782) on "Required actions workflows from branch protections should only be required if run" now (Q1 2024) includes an update from [Daniel Troger](https://github.com/danieltroger):

> We got an AMAZING workaround by Paul from GitHub enterprise support.
>
> It is a standalone workflow that polls the github API every minute for other workflows running for the same merge request and first completes once none is in progress anymore.
>
> - Create `.github/workflows/check_commit_status.yml` in your repo.
> - Add this yaml into it:
>
>   ```yaml
>   name: Confirm that all checks have passed or skipped
>   on:
>     pull_request:
>       types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
>       branches:
>         - main
>
>   jobs:
>     check_commit_status:
>       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>       steps:
>         - name: Confirm Check Runs
>           uses: actions/github-script@v7
>           with:
>             script: |
>               console.log("Sleeping 10s to give other runs a chance to start");
>               await sleep(10000);
>               const { owner, repo } = context.repo;
>               const commit_sha = context.payload.pull_request.head.sha; // Get the SHA of the head commit of the PR
>               const maxRetries = 15; // Maximum number of retries
>               const excludedCheckRunName = 'check_commit_status' // important you don't define name key for the job
>               let retryCount = 0;
>
>               async function fetchCheckRuns() {
>                 const response = await github.rest.checks.listForRef({
>                   owner,
>                   repo,
>                   ref: commit_sha,
>                   per_page: 100
>                 });
>                 return response.data.check_runs;
>               }
>               async function sleep(ms) {
>                 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
>               }
>               let checkRuns = await fetchCheckRuns();
>               let inProgressFound = false;
>               let failureFound = false;
>               do {
>                 inProgressFound = false;
>                 failureFound = false;
>                 for (const checkRun of checkRuns) {
>                   // exclude this job from the evaluation
>                   if (checkRun.name === excludedCheckRunName) {
>                     console.log(`Skipping excluded check run: ${checkRun.name}`);
>                     continue;
>                   }
>                   if (checkRun.status === 'in_progress') {
>                     inProgressFound = true;
>                     console.log(`Check run in progress: ${checkRun.name}`);
>                   }
>                   if (checkRun.conclusion === 'failure') {
>                     failureFound = true;
>                     console.log(`Check run failed: ${checkRun.name}`);
>                   }
>                 }
>                 if (inProgressFound) {
>                   if (retryCount >= maxRetries) {
>                     core.setFailed('Maximum retries reached with check runs still in progress.');
>                     break;
>                   }
>                   console.log('Waiting for 1 minute before rechecking...');
>                   await sleep(60000);
>                   checkRuns = await fetchCheckRuns();
>                   retryCount++;
>                 }
>               } while (inProgressFound);
>               if (failureFound) {
>                 core.setFailed('There are failed check runs.');
>                 }
>   ```
> - Set up a ruleset like this, that enforces above workflow to run before merging (make it manually bypassable as you wish)
>
> [image: ruleset]
>
> Edit: if you want to save github actions minutes by first starting the workaround workflow after some minutes, you can add `environment: delayenv` to the `check_commit_status` section above and follow these steps.
>
> > I am referencing the `delayenv` environment to delay this job from executing using the [wait timer protection](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#wait-timer) rule so that it gives the jobs to be checked time to run and finish.
> > The delay should be around the maximum amount of time you expect your other builds to take. This avoids unnecessary polling and consumption of minutes

---

In that same [issue 13690](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13690#discussioncomment-8382391), [Wechuli](https://github.com/wechuli) proposes:

> I've created a GitHub Action that wraps the logic of what @danieltroger described in a nicer package.
>
> Check it out at https://github.com/wechuli/allcheckspassed.
>
> It provides some additional options such as excluding certain checks from the evaluation and choosing what exactly constitutes a passing check (e.g. skipped, neutral).
> The action also creates a summary of the checks that were evaluated. Additional documentation is on the `README`.
>
> Ultimately this is only a workaround for a missing feature, the main downside it has is that you need to configure it on its own workflow and it will consume your Actions minutes, I have tried to document this under limitations section.

Example:

```yaml
name: All checks pass
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened, ready_for_review ]
  jobs:
    allchecks:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: wechuli/allcheckspassed@v1
```

With this default configuration, the action will fail if any of the checks on the pull request have failed or if any of the checks are still in progress, pending or queued when the workflow is complete.

The action also created a checks summary with details of each check that was evaluated and their status:

[image: https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/15605874/302626539-de9a3a20-02ff-4d96-8da5-0c8300d429e7.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.lx5UTIOsx-TMlIeutwR54WbZ-xmJIU0AlBptRphpAB8]